# Display quiz results for users

Tags: views, quiz

I am developing an e-learning portal for a client; the client wants to be able to create quizzes and view the results of individual students, and probably draw a graph to give an overview of student performance. I am using the Quiz module to create quizzes.

The "quiz score" is not available if you use node as the view base or quiz.

I am able to list username, level, and quiz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to add a relationship which would be the Quiz Result : User.

Then you would find the quiz result : score in the fields

Answer (score 2):

Use quiz as the base for view. 
If you want to create a chart.
Im using views [dataviz module](https://drupal.org/project/views_dataviz)

Code Karate have a tutorial on it [here.](http://youtu.be/1OLsNA8ef_E)

My view page ended up looking like this:
[image]

which created a chart based on the individual scores of the users answers (not the overall quiz:score) 
[image]