# How to aggregate field results to a chart?

Tags: 7, views, charts

I installed the [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module and I'm using it in my [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) display.

I have a field: **Score**

I added a chart but it shows two different charts (see image) instead of **just one** with all the results from that field.

[image]

How can I put them together? If it's with aggregation, can you give me some guides?

Here is how another attempt looks like:

[image]

And this is how my View currently looks like:

[image]

The tabular format of its data to be charted looks like so:

[image]

**Notes**:

- I'm using the [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module because I need the "radar" type which only exists in that module.
- I want to create a chart with all the scores displayed in the table, and not one chart per score.
- I don't want all the fields to appear as data, as in the last pictures in my question. I want the text to be the legend and the number to be the data.

Comment: did you check this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/43906/display-quiz-results-for-users

Comment: I just edited my post and added a few more images... Now it's in table format. See, I want to create a chart with all the scores displayed in the table, and not one chart per score...

Comment: I integrated relevant (I think) details in some of your comments in the "notes" part of your question now. Please review my edits of your question, and adapt/rework as you see fit (e.g. move those notes somewhere else in your question). After you do so, I suggest you also remove some of your comments in your question and my answer, to further cleanup things. Later on (probably tomorrow) I'll come back to my answer here, and try to further refine it as much as I can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of questions show up quite often. And each time I try to get them resolved with this very first attempt (if it is related to a Views display):

> You may find it easier to start with a "Table" display and convert it to a chart display after setting up the data. It can be easier to visualize what the result of the chart will be if it's been laid out in a table first.

In my experience, 90% of the issues turn out to be related to errors in the creation of the table that contains the data to be charted.

If this question is about creating a chart using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) integration, then refer to the appropriate Community documentation resources with more details about how to do so:

- For the **[Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart)** module: [Create charts using Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/2433497)
- For the **[Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts)** module: [Steps to create charts using the views UI](https://www.drupal.org/node/2426929).

**Disclosure**: I'm a (co-)maintainer of both [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) and [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts), and co-author of the documentation resources mentioned.

Comment: I'm using the chart module because I need the "radar" type which only exists in that module, but I can't find any information on your link... I have this (please check the two last pictures in my post, I edited) but I don't want all the fields to appear as data... I want the text to be the legend and the number to be tha data, and not showing up. I know i'm close, can you help me figure this out? Thank you...

Comment: I'm using the https://www.drupal.org/project/chart but now I see "We do not recommend using this module for any new projects". Maybe I should try it with another module... it's a shame 'cause I wanted the radar chart type. Should I try with charts?

Comment: I actually made it to work using the charts module!! But I can't find a radar chart. I don't know if it is possible to do it with highcharts library but I couldn't, maybe something wrong on the installation... If I post this as a new question, will you be able to answer it? Thank you

Comment: You're going too fast for me (I can't keep up with answering all your questions). Good to hear you made some progress by using charts (as I recommended). And as in my prior comment: yes go ahead and create a NEW question. "Later on" (maybe only tomorrow?) I will also try to answer that one ... Here is already a hint about what part of my answer to such question will include: https://www.drupal.org/files/RadarGraph.png ... That's what "I" think a  "Radar" chart looks like, is that similar to what "you" call a radar chart? If so, your new question could be as simple as "How did you do that?!?!".

Comment: Yes!! How did you do that?!?! http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/183596/how-to-add-a-radar-chart-to-views

Comment: You seem to be in a hurry ... But I'm still working on refining "this" answer (but in my own envir, since drupal.SE does not support "save drafts"). So if I (temporary) put "refining my answer here" on hold, so that I can answer your other question first, will you then later on (after I completed my refinement to this answer) reconsider my answer here (to check if you think it's worth marking it as accepted)?

Comment: I'm sorry if I went too fast here. As I said I figured a way to display a chart (currently a column chart) to my views. So everything is working great except that I would prefer having a radar chart. If you have the answer to this today or tomorrow, I can wait. Thank you so much for your time and patience!!